# What is document model for each java POJO in couchbase

Tags: java, json, couchbase

I am newbie to couchbase document oriented NoSQL database. I have some doubts regarding documents in couchbase.

In Mongo DB there will be separate document model with list of documents under collections for each POJO class as like in RDBMS. But, in couchbase i can see all document's are inserting under the specified bucket.

My question is how to separate the list of document's under each document model(i.e., table in RDBMS) or is it possible only by using views in CB.

Let's say in this order,
Beer_Documents -> Json Document data's
Breweries -> Json Document data's

In mongoDB i can see like above. Anyone could help me to know about this...

TIA..,

Answer (score 2):

having a field with the document's type and a view to list all documents of each type is a possibility. until N1QL, it's the only possibility to get a collection of documents for which you don't know the list of keys in advance...

another possible modelization is to have the type of the document in its key, like "brewery::1", "beer:1"... you still need a view to get all of them though.

lastly, you can manage lookup documents yourself (documents that contain a list of keys of the type you're interested in for instance).

Comment: Basle Thanks for your answer. So, we need to keep document type json field in list of document's to identify the corresponding POJO(i.e., table) document model and then using that we need to create the view based on that document type to query the document's to get the list of documents by doc type,to filter etc.., If i am wrong take to correct path

Comment: @DIVA yes, that is correct. Something like: {"type"="beer", "name":"budlight", "category":"yucky"}